# Can my thread help the OS decide when to context switch it out?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, context-switch

I am working on a threaded application on Linux in C++ which attempts to be real time, doing an action on a heartbeat, or as close to it as possible.

In practice, I find the OS is swapping out my thread and causing delays of up to a tenth of a second while it is switched out, causing the heartbeat to be irregular.

Is there a way my thread can hint to the OS that now is a good time to context switch it out?  I could make this call right after doing a heartbeat, and thus minimize the delay due to an ill timed context switch.

Comment: "causing delays of up to a tenth of a second"
I really doubt that context switching by the OS is delaying you 100ms. I'd bet there's something else going on here.

Comment: If you want to have a stable response time, you really need RT threads (and, may be RT-enabled kernel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to say what the main problem is in your case, but it is most certainly not something that can be corrected with a call to `sched_yield()` or `pthread_yield()`. The only well-defined use for yielding, in Linux, is to allow a different ready thread to preempt the currently CPU-bound running thread at the same priority on the same CPU under SCHED_FIFO scheduling policy. Which is a poor design decision in almost all cases.

If you're serious about your goal of "attempting to be real-time" in Linux, then first of all, you should be using a real-time `sched_setscheduler` setting (SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR, FIFO preferred).
Second, get the full preemption patch for Linux (from [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/) if your distro does not supply one. It will also give you the ability to reschedule device driver threads and to execute your thread higher than, say, hard disk or ethernet driver threads.
Third, see [RTWiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) and other resources for more hints on how to design and set up a real-time application.

This should be enough to get you under 10 *micro*seconds response time, regardless of system load on any decent desktop system. I have an embedded system where I only squeeze out 60 us response idle and 150 us under heavy disk/system load, but it's still orders of magnitude faster than what you're describing.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the current executing thread to pause execution with various commands such as [yield](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html).

Just telling the thread to pause is non-determanistic, 999 times it might provide good intervals and 1 time it doesn't.

You'll will probably want to look at *real time scheduling* for consistant results.  This site http://www2.net.in.tum.de/~gregor/docs/pthread-scheduling.html seems to be a good starting spot for researching about thread scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

use `sched_yield`

And fur threads there is an  `pthread_yield`  http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html

Comment: `pthread_yield` is just a useless nonstandard alias for `sched_yield`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by the question. If your program is just waiting on a periodic heartbeat and then doing some work, then the OS should know to schedule other things when you go back to waiting on the heartbeat.

You aren't spinning on a flag to get your "heartbeat" are you?

Answer (score 1):

You *are* using a timer function such as `setitimer()`, right? **RIGHT???**

If not, then you are doing it all wrong.

You may need to specify a timer interval that is just a little shorter than what you really need. If you are using a real-time scheduler priority and a timer, your process will almost always be woken up on time.

I would say always on time, but Linux isn't a perfect real-time OS yet.

Comment: `setitimer` is deprecated in favor of `timer_create`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure for Linux, but on Windows it's been explained that [you can't ask the system to *not* interrupt you for several reasons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100426-00/?p=14243) (first paragraph mostly). Off my head, one of the reasons is hardware interrupts that can occur at any time and over which you have no control.

*EDIT* Some guy just suggested the use of [`sched_yield`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield) then deleted his answer. It'll relinquish time for your whole process though. You can also use [`sched_setscheduler`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler) to hint the kernel about what you need.